# package github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2: cannot find package "github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2" in any of:

Tags: go

I want to use Golang email template 
and when I run

> go get -u github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2
>   it returns
>
> package github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2: cannot find package "github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2" in any of:
>           /usr/local/go/src/github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2 (from $GOROOT)
>           /home/User/go/src/github.com/matcornic/hermes/v2 (from $GOPATH)

My go Variables

```
GOPATH - /home/User/go
GOROOT - /usr/local/go
GOBIN -
```

I fight with this error the whole day, But I can't find out a solution. Please help me.

I set MY gopath to another directory several times but it does not work

I am writing code in this directory

```
/home/User/go/src/Go-Web
```

and inside Go-Web my current project lies

Comment: It's because it doesn't exist. https://github.com/matcornic/hermes contains no subdirectory `v2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the README:

> Starting from release v2.0.0, Hermes uses Go modules. The latest version of Hermes requires Go 1.11 with gomodules enabled. You can still use an Hermes release compatible with prior Go versions by using v1.2.0 release

Either turn on [the module feature](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) by unsetting GOPATH, or use version 1 of the package (`github.com/matcornic/hermes`, without the version suffix).